# Is it a problem if my Admob Banner is not showing in small devices ? (it is like hidden under the screen)

Tags: java, android, android-layout, admob, ads

So my app is working fine, but I have noticed that in small devices of 3.4" (480x800) in one activity as the admob banner is at the buttom of the screen and and the UI of my app doesn't fit everything on the screen because the device is so small, the admob banner is like hidden. I have 2 linear layouts and one frame layout where the banner is. The 3 layouts are like 3 blocks on top of each other. So the third block(the one at the button -- the frame layout where the banner is) doesn't enter the screen, so the banner is like under the buttom part of the screen so it is not shown (I mean, it is shown but the user can't see it). Could this be a problem ? Should I delete that banner? I don't mind having less impressions but I am afraid that it could be a reason of admob ban...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a violation, especially because in some devices only a part of this banner is shown which is a violation.

You can remove the banner or make the whole activity scrollable so if the user scroll down they will see the ad.